# Mailchimp API 3.0 - Add / remove a user to a list > group > group name

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to use the Mailchimp API 3.0 to insert a user into a list > group > group name with php.

I found a nice example using curl, [here it is](http://rudrastyh.com/api/mailchimp-subscription.html), but, as you can see, here he shows only to add a user into a list, and not in group > group name.

The problem is that I can't find documentation about adding or deleting a user from groups.

I've tried to add the group into the json data array with label 'interests' and also to add it in the $merge_fields array ( I think this is for v2.0 ), but without success.

Comment: Could you add the code of what you've tried?

Comment: Ever get a solution on this? I have a need to remove a large number of users from an interest group.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it you need to make a call to a `lists/{list-id}/member/{member-hash}` endpoint with a body like this this:

```
   {
      "email_address": "someone@doamin.com",
      "status": "subscribed",
      "interests": {
          <interest_id>: true,
          <interest_id>: false
      }
   }
```

Mailchimp has some example JSON here: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#